I trying to create a NAT GATEWAY module but i have the result below after terraform plan
Main.tf:
# allocate elastic ip. this eip will be used for the nat-gateway in the public subnet az1 
resource "aws_eip" "eip_for_nat_gateway_az1" {
  vpc    = true

  tags   = {
    Name = "nat gateway az1 eip"
  }
}

# allocate elastic ip. this eip will be used for the nat-gateway in the public subnet az2

resource "aws_eip" "eip_for_nat_gateway_az2" {
  vpc    = true

  tags   = {
    Name = "nat gateway az2 eip"
  }
}

# create nat gateway in public subnet az1
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gateway_az1" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.eip_for_nat_gateway_az1.id
  subnet_id     = var.public_subnet_az1_id

  tags   = {
    Name = "nat gateway az1"
  }

  # to ensure proper ordering, it is recommended to add an explicit dependency
  depends_on = [var.internet_gateway]
}

# create nat gateway in public subnet az2
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat_gateway_az2" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.eip_for_nat_gateway_az2
  subnet_id     = var.public_subnet_az2_id

  tags   = {
    Name = "nat gateway az2"
  }

  # to ensure proper ordering, it is recommended to add an explicit dependency
  # on the internet gateway for the vpc.
  depends_on = [var.internet_gateway]
}

# create private route table az1 and add route through nat gateway az1
resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table_az1" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id

  route {
    cidr_block      = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id  = aws_nat_gateway.nat_gateway_az1.id
  }

  tags   = {
    Name = "private route table az1"
  }
}

# associate private app subnet az1 with private route table az1
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_app_subnet_az1_route_table_az1_association" {
  subnet_id         = var.private_app_subnet_az1_id
  route_table_id    = aws_route_table.private_route_table_az1.id
}

# associate private data subnet az1 with private route table az1
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_data_subnet_az1_route_table_az1_association" {
  subnet_id         = var.private_data_subnet_az1_id
  route_table_id    = aws_route_table.private_route_table_az1.id
}

# create private route table az2 and add route through nat gateway az2
resource "aws_route_table" "private_route_table_az2" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id

  route {
    cidr_block      = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id  = aws_nat_gateway.nat_gateway_az2.id
  }

  tags   = {
    Name = "private route table az2"
  }
}

# associate private app subnet az2 with private route table az2
resource "aws_route_table_association" 
"private_app_subnet_az2_route_table_az2_association" {
  subnet_id         = var.private_app_subnet_az2_id
  route_table_id    = aws_route_table.private_route_table_az2.id
}

# associate private data subnet az2 with private route table az2
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_data_subnet=az2_route_table_az2_association" {
  subnet_id         = var.private_data_subnet_az2_id
  route_table_id    = aws_route_table.private_route_table_az2.id
}

variable.tf
variable "vpc_id" {}
variable "public_subnet_az1_id" {}
variable "internet_gateway" {}
variable "public_subnet_az2_id" {}
variable "private_app_subnet_az1_id" {}
variable "private_app_subnet_az2_id" {}
variable "private_data_subnet_az1_id" {}
variable "private_data_subnet_az2_id" {}

I get tis reponse from executing terraform plan
Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 28, in module "NAT-gateway":
│   28:     public_subnet_az1_id                 = module.vpc.public_subnet_az1_id        
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "public_subnet_az1_id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 30, in module "NAT-gateway":
│   30:     public_subnet_az2_id                 = module.vpc.public_subnet_az2_id        
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "public_subnet_az2_id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 32, in module "NAT-gateway":
│   32:     private_app_subnet_az1_id            = module.vpc.private_app_subnet_az1_idb  
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "private_app_subnet_az1_idb".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 33, in module "NAT-gateway":
│   33:     private_app_subnet_az2_id            = module.vpc.private_app_subnet_az2_id   
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "private_app_subnet_az2_id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 34, in module "NAT-gateway":
│   34:     private_data_subnet_az1_id           = module.vpc.private_data_subnet_az1_id  
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "private_data_subnet_az1_id".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 35, in module "NAT-gateway":
│   35:     private_data_subnet_az2_id           = module.vpc.private_data_subnet_az2_id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "private_data_subnet_az2_id".
╵

I don't see why I get this response. I think the setup is correct. Any help is appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
